# Find latitude and longitude using CLGeocoder

Tags: iphone, ios, mapkit, clgeocoder

I am trying to find latitude and longitude by giving address string. I am getting 0.000 and 0.000 for both the values.

I am using MapKit, iOS 7, XCode 5

```
CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
[geocoder geocodeAddressString:@"Fairfax, VA" completionHandler:^(NSArray* placemarks, NSError* error){
    for (CLPlacemark* aPlacemark in placemarks)
    {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;

        coordinate.longitude = aPlacemark.location.coordinate.longitude;
        coordinate.latitude = aPlacemark.location.coordinate.latitude;

        // updatedCoordinates is a property in my class and I am setting it's value 
        // here and using it in bunch of other places.
        self.updatedCoordinates = coordinate;
    }
}];
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? Check the value of (NSError *error). Also you are in a loop constantly overwriting the value of self.updatedCoordinates.

Comment: I'm not familiar with MapKit, but did you check the `NSError`? There is maybe a error there.

Comment: No, I am not getting any error. The program is not stepping inside the completionHandler at all.

Comment: Is `placemarks` nil or empty? (No results)

Comment: Are you doing this from an active queue or run loop mode? If it's in your mail thread, the completion handler should be called, even if with an empty array of results. Do you get to even the start of the `for` loop?

Comment: no, I don't get to the for loop.

Answer (score 3):

```c
-(void)getPlacemarkInfo:(NSString*)placeName {
    // place name can be paris, etc
    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    [geocoder geocodeAddressString:placeName completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"%@", error);    
        } else {
            CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks lastObject];
     //     placemark.location.coordinate.latitude; will returns latitude
     //     placemark.location.coordinate.longitude; will returns longitude
        }
    }];
}
```